# Session in WCF not consistent

Tags: c#, wcf, session

I am trying to use session in my WCF service (webHttp), but the session is not
consistent between requests (When I make the second call to the service the session is not NULL, but the key I inserted doesn't exist and the session ID is different).

I checked and the default InstanceContextMode is PerSession, which as I understand should be suitable for my requirements.

Are there any other configurations I need for using session in WCF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a binding that supports reliable sessions, such as these:

- HTTP-based transport standard bindings:

  **WsHttpBinding** and expose request-reply or one-way contracts.

  Can be used when using reliable session over a request-reply or
  simple one-way service contract.

  **WsDualHttpBinding** and expose duplex, request-reply, or one-way
  contracts.

  **WsFederationHttpBinding** and expose request-reply or one-way
  contracts.
- TCP-based transport standard bindings:

  **NetTcpBinding** and expose duplex, request reply, or one-way contracts.

Look here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136.aspx

Comment: Sessions and reliable sessions are not the same thing. A session is simply a mechanism that the service uses to understand multiple messages are coming form the same proxy. It doesn't say anything about tracking a sequence of messages. Reliable sessions is an implementation of WS-ReliableMessaging. As it turns out of course, you can't implement WS-ReliableMessaging unless you know that the messages have come from the same client (in fact WSHttpBinding can use WS-ReliableMessaging to implement its notion of WCF session although by default, if available, it uses WS-SecureConversation)